# Is there a way to bypass the namespace/module name in Python?

Tags: python, module, namespaces, styles

If you have a module like `module`, can you bypass it and use the functions available inside without using the module?

I imported the module, but the compiler still complains not having to find `function`. I still have to use `module.function()`.

It has many more functions, so I don't want to redefine them one by one but just avoid typing `module` if possible.

Comment: Do you know about `from module import *` ?

Comment: Thanks I assumed that was done for functions implicitly. Now it works. Is there a way to limit the import to all functions? Because it also has other types, etc. Just wondering.

Comment: In your `module`, you can define a variable named `__all__` that contains names of everything that will be imported by `*`.

Comment: The names imported from a module may be controlled by setting the `__all__` variable in the module itself. This allows the designer of  modules to define what should be imported by `import *`. A module user has to accept the predefined list (if any) or explicitly provide a list of names to import `from module import name1,name2,...`.

Comment: That's a neat trick, although it's not my module, so can't modify it. It's ok though, was just curious.

Comment: you could still do it by simply making your own module which imports the names you want, and then import that .. :P

Comment: Thanks alot guys, I only needed a couple functions but still was curious. Being able to import everything by type seems useful though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Importing in Python just adds stuff to your namespace. How you qualify imported names is the difference between `import foo` and `from foo import bar`.

In the first case, you would only import the module name `foo`, and that's how you would reach anything in it, which is why you need to do `foo.bar()`. The second case, you explicitly import *only* `bar`, and now you can call it thus: `bar()`.

`from foo import *` will import all *importable* names (those defined in a special variable [`__all__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834/can-someone-explain-all-in-python)) into the current namespace. This, although works - is not recommend because you may end up accidentally overwriting an existing name.

```
foo = 42
from bar import * # bar contains a `foo`
print foo # whatever is from `bar`
```

The best practice is to import whatever you need:

`from foo import a,b,c,d,e,f,g`

Or you can alias the name

`import foo as imported_foo`

Bottom line - try to avoid `from foo import *`.